# Issue with composite type in an UPSERT function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, plpgsql, upsert

I have a function in PostgreSQL 9.1 called `fun_test`. It has a composite type as input parameter and I keep getting a casting error when I call it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION netcen.fun_test(myobj netcen.testobj)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
tmp_code smallint;
cur_member refcursor;
BEGIN
-- Check if the member exists first
OPEN cur_member FOR 
EXECUTE 'SELECT testkey FROM netcen.test WHERE testkey=' || myobj.testkey ;
FETCH cur_member INTO tmp_code;
CLOSE cur_member;
CASE tmp_code
    WHEN COALESCE(tmp_code,0)=0 THEN
    -- Record not found INSERT a new record
    -- will skip user defined validation for now
    insert into netcen.test values(myobj.testkey,
    myobj.tes,
    myobj.testname);

    ELSE
    -- Record found UPDATE the record
    update netcen.test set 
    test=myobj.test,
    testname=myobj.testname  WHERE testkey=myobj.testkey;

END CASE;
END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Below is the type `testobj`

```
CREATE TYPE netcen.testobj AS
   (testkey smallint,
    tes text,
    testname text);
```

When I call the function:

```
SELECT netcen.fun_test('(3,khaendra@me.com,khaendra)':: netcen.testobj);
```

.. I get the following error message:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: smallint = boolean
LINE 1: SELECT "__Case__Variable_8__" IN (COALESCE(tmp_code,0)=0)
                                      ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s).
       You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT "__Case__Variable_8__" IN (COALESCE(tmp_code,0)=0)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "fun_test" line 11 at CASE
```

Where should I cast?
Definition of the table `netcen.test`:

```
CREATE TABLE netcen.test    (
  testkey smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  tes netcen.dom_email_validation,
  testname text,
  CONSTRAINT key PRIMARY KEY (testkey)
)
```

---

@ Erwin, thanks for the links. I read and have modified my function to this, please go through it and tell me if it can work well with several clients calling the same function concurrently?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION netcen.fun_test_modified(myobj netcen.test)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
myoutput boolean :=false;
BEGIN
    update netcen.test set 
    tes=myobj.tes,
    testname=myobj.testname  WHERE testkey=myobj.testkey;
IF FOUND THEN
        myoutput:= TRUE;
        RETURN myoutput;
    END IF;
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO netcen.test values(myobj.testkey,
    myobj.tes,
    myobj.testname);
    myoutput:= TRUE;
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        update netcen.test set 
    tes=myobj.tes,
    testname=myobj.testname  WHERE testkey=myobj.testkey;
    myoutput:= TRUE;
    END;
    RETURN myoutput;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I have done away with the type test and just used the table `test`! I didn't know that could work!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Answer

The **error** occurs here:

```
CASE tmp_code
    WHEN COALESCE(tmp_code,0)=0 THEN
```

Works like this:

```
CASE WHEN COALESCE(tmp_code,0)=0 THEN
```

You mixed two different syntax variants of [PL/pgSQL `CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) ("simple" vs. "searched") in an incompatible way.

There is **another error**:

```
update netcen.test set 
test=myobj.test,
testname=myobj.testname  WHERE testkey=myobj.testkey;
```

Did you mean:

```
UPDATE test
SET    tes = myobj.tes
     , testname = myobj.testname
WHERE  testkey = myobj.testkey;
```

There is also no need for `CREATE TYPE netcen.testobj ...`. You can use the table name `netcen.test` as type name.

### You really want to "UPSERT"

In Postgres **9.5 or later** use the new UPSERT (`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`). Like:

- [UPSERT with ON CONFLICT using values from source table in the UPDATE part](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134493/upsert-with-on-conflict-using-values-from-source-table-in-the-update-part/134538#134538)

---

For **older versions** you can emulate an **`UPSERT`**. The *simple form* in plpgsql, without concurrency:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_test(myobj testobj)
  RETURNS boolean
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN    
   UPDATE test
   SET    tes = myobj.tes
        , testname = myobj.testname
   WHERE  testkey = myobj.testkey;

   IF FOUND THEN
      RETURN FALSE;
   ELSE
      INSERT INTO test SELECT (myobj).*;
      RETURN TRUE;
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

Could just be plain SQL with a **[data-modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)**:

```
WITH my_row(testkey, tes, testname) AS (
    SELECT 1::smallint, 'khaendra@me.net', 'khaendra'
    )
, u AS (
    UPDATE test t
    SET    tes = m.tes
         , testname = m.testname
    FROM   my_row m
    WHERE  t.testkey = m.testkey
    RETURNING t.testkey
    )
INSERT INTO test (testkey, tes, testname)
SELECT * FROM my_row
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM u);
```

The time window for a possible race condition is *extremely* tiny with this form (single combined statement). If **concurrency** is still an issue (heavy concurrent write load), then ...

#### Your function reviewed

If the function returns, the row has been inserted or updated. The only other way is an `EXCEPTION` of a different kind. The returned value `true` is just noise. (Might be more interesting to return `true` for `INSERT` and `false` for `UPDATE`.) So I simplified:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION netcen.fun_test_modified(myobj netcen.test)
  RETURNS boolean
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   UPDATE netcen.test
   SET    tes = myobj.tes
        , testname = myobj.testname
   WHERE  testkey = myobj.testkey;

   IF FOUND THEN
      RETURN true;
   END IF;

   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO netcen.test 
      SELECT (myobj).*;  -- simpler form, parenthesis needed.

   EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN   -- cleaner
      UPDATE netcen.test
      SET    tes = myobj.tes
           , testname = myobj.testname
      WHERE  testkey = myobj.testkey;
   END;
   RETURN true;
END
$func$;
```

Related answers on SO:

- [Upsert with a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17153361/939860)
- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15950324/939860)

[Blog post on UPSERT by Depesz](https://www.depesz.com/2012/06/10/why-is-upsert-so-complicated/).

Comment: what do you mean if concurrency is not an issue?

Comment: @indago: Concurrency is an issue in databases where multiple clients might try to INSERT / UPDATE at the same time. There is a very slim chance for a race condition. Read the article I link to or try the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/mvcc.html).

Comment: @ Erwin, concurrency is an issue ofcourse because more than ten clients will be connected and working at the same time on this database,thats why i want all the inserts and updates to be handled in the database by functions like these. can i still use the functions you gave me up here? please give me a modified version that caters for concurrency. Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: @indago: I did. Follow the link at the end of my answer.

Comment: please check out my modifications to the function below and tell me your comments, i need the function to return a boolean value so that the client application can know if the record has been inserted/updated correctly or not

Comment: @indago: Looks good. I added a review to my answer.

Comment: you talked of (Might be more interesting to return TRUE for INSERT and FALSE for UPDATE.) and thats true,can i modify the return type to be text then return actual text? i heard of raise notice but am not sure how they are used

Comment: @indago: Sure you can return `text`. Just do it. If you run into problems, post another *question*, not a comment here.

Answer (score 6):

While klin is technically right in his answer about how to fix your current function, let me question your whole approach.  What you try to achieve is called 'UPSERT' and with PostgreSQL 9.1 (which offers [writable CTEs](http://www.depesz.com/2011/03/16/waiting-for-9-1-writable-cte/)) you have a very simple way to achieve this.  I omitted the function definition for the sake of clarity, but you can easily wrap it in a query language function (that is, ending in `LANGUAGE sql`):

```
WITH upd AS (
    UPDATE netcen.test 
    SET (test, testname) = ($1.test, $1.testname)
    WHERE testkey =  $1.testkey
    RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO netcen.test (
    testkey,
    test, 
    testname
)
VALUES (
    $1.testkey,
    $1.tes,
    $1.testname
)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM upd
);
```

This way you can avoid using an expensive cursor, and an even more expensive `EXCEPTION` clause.

Note that this is basically the same solution as one of the several Erwin provides in his answer (for historical reasons, two questions were merged into one with all their answers).  So the warning about concurrency applies to this one as well.

Comment: @Deszo, thanks for the clean approach,will this support concurrency?

Answer (score 3):

Insetad of

```
CASE tmp_code
    WHEN COALESCE(tmp_code, 0) = 0 THEN
```

use

```
IF COALESCE(tmp_code, 0) = 0 THEN
    ...
END IF;
```

Note that "tmp_code" is smallint
while "COALESCE(tmp_code, 0) = 0" is boolean.

Another bug - function returns boolean but doesn't have return instruction.

If netcen.test.testkey is a primary key you can use [exception (39.6.6)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html), especially look at Example 39-2 - it's just what you want to do.