# How to pass a table type with an array field to a function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, functions, postgresql-9.1, array

i have a table called book

```
CREATE TABLE book
(
  id smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,       
  bname text,       
  btype text,
  bprices numeric(11,2)[],
  CONSTRAINT key PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
```

and a function save_book

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save_book(thebook book)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
myoutput text :='Nothing has occured';
BEGIN

    update book set 
    bname=thebook.bname,
    btype=thebook.btype,bprices=thebook.bprices  WHERE id=thebook.id;

    IF FOUND THEN
        myoutput:= 'Record with PK[' || thebook.id || '] successfully updated';
        RETURN myoutput;
    END IF;

    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO book values(thebook.id,thebook.bname,thebook.btype,
        thebook.bprices);
        myoutput:= 'Record successfully added';           
    END;
 RETURN myoutput;

    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

now when i call the function

```
SELECT save_book('(179,the art of war,fiction,{190,220})'::book);
```

i get the error

```
ERROR: malformed array literal: "{190"
SQL state: 22P02
Character: 18
```

i dont understand because i dont see any error in the format of the array, any help?

Comment: Your function looks a bit overcomplicated for me, but anways.  An array literal must be enclosed by single quotes, so try the following: `ave_book((179,the art of war,fiction,'{190,220}')::book`.  The constructed row does not need the quotes.

Comment: when i run that i get the error 
`ERROR: syntax error at or near "art"`

Comment: Individual string literals must still be enclosed in quotation marks.

Comment: Sorry, the correct one is `ave_book((179, 'the art of war', 'fiction', '{190,220}')::book`, just as Andriy said.

Comment: @dezso: Seems an answer to me. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sort of thing gets complicated.  I am working on some related projects right now.  The basic tweak is that PostgreSQL uses a format which uses double quotes internally in tuple representation to represent literal values, so:

```
SELECT save_book('(179,the art of war,fiction,"{190,220}")'::book);
```

should work.  In essence a neat trick is creating a csv and enclosing in tuple or array identifiers.  The big issue is that you have to deal with escaping (doubling quotes at every level as needed).  So the following is exactly equivalent:

```
SELECT save_book('(179,"the art of war","fiction","{""190"",""220""}")'::book);
```

The second approach is to use a row constructor:

```
SELECT save_book(row(179,'the art of war','fiction', array[190,220])::book);
```

The first solution has the obvious advantage of being able to take advantage of existing programming frameworks for CSV generation and escaping.  The second is cleanest in SQL.  They can be mixed and matched.

Comment: +1 for using an array constructor, escaping can be a nightmare

Comment: @Chris, The first solution seems good and for me i think is the best!

Comment: @JackDouglas, one thing we are looking at doing is going the first route in LSMB specifically because we can use CSV frameworks that are already working.

Answer (score 6):

If you ever wonder about the correct syntax for a row type, ask Postgres. It should know:

```
SELECT b FROM book b LIMIT 1;  -- or: WHERE id = 179;
```

Which will return a text representation of your row in valid format:

```
(179,"the art of war",fiction,"{190,220}")
```

- Values of columns are represented as an unquoted, comma-separated list, enclosed in paretheses.
- Double quotes are use around values, if there can be ambiguity - including text with white space. While in this particular case the double-quotes around `"the art of war"` are optional, the double-quotes around `"{190,220}"` are necessary for an array.

Enclose the string in single quotes, modify and test:

```
SELECT '(333,the art of war,fiction,"{191,220,235}")'::book
```

---

#### Function reviewed

Consider what we discussed under the related, preceding question:
[Issue with composite type in an UPSERT function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33319/casting-issue-when-calling-a-function-with-composite-type-parameter)

A separate [block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-structure.html) (`BEGIN .. END;`) is only useful if you want to catch the `EXCEPTION` an `INSERT` might raise. Since a **block with exception** carries some overhead, it makes sense to have a separate block that might never be entered:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save_book(thebook book)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
   UPDATE book
   SET    bname =   thebook.bname
         ,btype =   thebook.btype
         ,bprices = thebook.bprices
   WHERE  id = thebook.id;

   IF FOUND THEN
      RETURN format('Record with PK[%s] successfully updated', thebook.id);
   END IF;

   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO book SELECT (thebook).*;
      RETURN format('Record with PK[%s] successfully inserted', thebook.id);

   EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
      UPDATE book
      SET    bname =   thebook.bname
            ,btype =   thebook.btype
            ,bprices = thebook.bprices
      WHERE  id = thebook.id;
   END;

   RETURN format('Record with PK[%s] successfully updated', thebook.id);
END
$BODY$  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Else, **simplify**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save_book(thebook book)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
   UPDATE book
   SET    bname =   thebook.bname
         ,btype =   thebook.btype
         ,bprices = thebook.bprices
   WHERE  id = thebook.id;

   IF FOUND THEN
      RETURN format('Record with PK[%s] successfully updated', thebook.id);
   END IF;

   INSERT INTO book SELECT (thebook).*;
   RETURN format('Record with PK[%s] successfully inserted', thebook.id);
END
$BODY$  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

I also simplified your `INSERT` statement. It's safe to omit the column list from INSERT under the given circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

While I don't see the real advantage of your solution, I mean passing a row to the function instead of passing the individual values as in

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save_book2(
      integer
    , text
    , text
    , integer[]
)
RETURNS text AS
...
```

Anyway, your solution works as well if you call the function correctly:

```
SELECT ave_book((179, 'the art of war', 'fiction', '{190,220}')::book);
```

That is, the record expression doesn't need quoting, while the text values and the array literal do.

Comment: I made that function to handle all inserts and updates shielding the application from directly dealing with the tables, do you think that having that function does not add any advantage?

Comment: My $0.02 on the design decision.  I think it has a great advantage provided you have application code to look up the structure of the type involved and construct the argument for you.  This gives you a discoverable API which is very helpful.  Without that, however, it means that if your table structure changes you have extra places to make a change which is definitely not good.  I say this being one who is moving my development in the direction you are going, and on the whole I think it is a good idea.  It does have dangers though.