# UPSERT with ON CONFLICT using values from source table in the UPDATE part

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, upsert

Given:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
PK_A INT8 NOT NULL,
A INT8,
PRIMARY KEY (PK_A)
);

CREATE TABLE B (
PK_B INT8 NOT NULL,
B INT8,
PRIMARY KEY (PK_B)
);
```

This query:

```
insert into table_b (pk_b, b) 
select pk_a,a from table_a 
on conflict (b) do update set b=a;
```

causes the following error:

> ```
> ERROR:  column "a" does not exist
> LINE 1: ...elect pk_a,a from table_a on conflict (b) do update set b=a;
>                                                                  ^
> HINT:  There is a column named "a" in table "*SELECT*", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
> ```

How to do the update while referring to content of `table_a`?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE A...` creates table `a`, not `table_a`.

Comment: the `do update set b = a;` can't find "a" because there reference to Table "b" and not to the Subquery, try `do update set b = (select a from a);`

Answer (score 46):

Multiple problems.
Your setup, extended:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  pk_a int PRIMARY KEY 
, a int
, comment text  -- added column to make effect clear
);

CREATE TABLE b (
  pk_b int PRIMARY KEY
, b int 
, comment text
);

INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, 11, 'comment from a')
                   , (2, 22, 'comment from a');

INSERT INTO b VALUES (1, 77, 'comment from b');
```

This works:

```
INSERT INTO b (pk_b, b, comment) 
SELECT pk_a, a, comment
FROM   a 
ON     CONFLICT (pk_b) DO UPDATE  -- conflict is on the unique column
SET    b = excluded.b;            -- key word "excluded", refer to target column
```

Result:

```
TABLE b;

 pk_b | b  |    comment
------+----+----------------
    1 | 11 | comment from b   -- updated
    2 | 22 | comment from a   -- inserted
```

#### The problems

0. You are confusing `table_a` and `A` in your demo (like [@Abelisto commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134493/upsert-using-on-conflict-from-source-table-with-update-from-source-table/134538#comment252611_134493)).

   Using legal, lower-case, unquoted identifiers helps to avoid confusion.
1. Like [@Ziggy mentioned](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/134501/3684), `ON CONFLICT` only works for actual **unique or exclusion constraint violations**. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)

   > The optional `ON CONFLICT` clause specifies an alternative action to raising a unique violation or exclusion constraint violation error.

   Consequently, <strike>`ON CONFLICT (b)`</strike> cannot work, no constraint there. `ON CONFLICT (pk_b)` works.
2. Like [@Ziggy also mentioned](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/134501/3684), ***source* table names are not visible** in the `UPDATE` part. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)

   > The `SET` and `WHERE` clauses in `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` have access
   > to the existing row using the table's name (or an alias), and to
   > **rows proposed for insertion using the special `excluded` table**.

   Bold emphasis mine.
3. You also cannot use column names of the *source* table in the `UPDATE` part. It must be **column names of the *target* row**. So you really want:

   ```
    SET    b = excluded.b
   ```

   [The manual once more:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)

   > Note that the effects of all per-row `BEFORE INSERT` triggers are
   > reflected in excluded values, since those effects may have contributed
   > to the row being excluded from insertion.

Comment: thanks for this explanation, now i know why the `b = excluded.a` can't work, it was a little bit hidden in the official Docu.

Comment: simple one liner for dummies like: 'excluded' points to new incoming data which you want to insert or persists in table.

Answer (score 12):

When doing upserts in PostgreSQL 9.5+ you must refer to the excluded data (that which failed to insert) by the alias `excluded`. Also, the `on conflict` option must refer to the key: `(pk_b)` rather than `(b)`. Eg.

```
insert into table_b (pk_b, b) 
select pk_a,a from table_a 
on conflict (pk_b) do update set b=excluded.b;
```

For more information refer to the official documentation or [this easy introduction to upsert](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What's_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#INSERT_..._ON_CONFLICT_DO_NOTHING.2FUPDATE_.28.22UPSERT.22.29).

Comment: This query does **not** work.